# python deepcopy not removing internal references in list extended using * operator?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I have the following code. I extended the list of dicts (`l1`) by `l1*3`, deepcopy and assigned to `l2`. Now when I modify first element in `l2`, other corresponding elements in `l2` also gets modified. So deepcopy does not remove the reference created by `*` operator on list of dicts ?

```
import copy
l1 = [{'a':1},{'b':2}]
l2 = copy.deepcopy(l1*3)
print(l2)
l2[0]['a'] = 7 # Why this changed ['a'] to 7 in all dicts in l2, even after deepcopy?
print(l2)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
[{'a': 7}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 7}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 7}, {'b': 2}]
```

Expected: (Only first element should modify)

```
[{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
[{'a': 7}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
```

I have already found following solution to get expected output:

```
l2 = [d.copy() for d in l1*3]
```

**Can someone share an explanation for why the deepcopy did not work in first code. ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`deepcopy` *intentionally* replicates any aliased references within the structure being copied. It maintains a `memo` dictionary of objects already copied during the current copy operation, and when the same object is seen again, it inserts an alias to the already copied object. Among other things, this makes it safe with recursive data structures (where a non-memoized `deepcopy` would recurse forever until it ran out of memory and died).

If you want the individual elements to be unaliased, `deepcopy` them individually, e.g.:

```
 l2 = [copy.deepcopy(x) for x in l1*3]
```

where the separated `deepcopy` operations maintain separate memoization dictionaries.